# Модуль что-то вроде pyautogui для Android ОС в Python

Tags: python, android

Я хочу сделать что-то похожее на автокликер в Python. Посоветуйте модуль автомотизации по типу pyautogui, который поддерживает операционную систему Android

Answer (score 0):

на kivy можно сделать с gui андроида